# Crashed powershell and pegged my CPU with Regex - how/why?

Tags: regex, powershell, crash

After executing the below command my powershell pegged at 97% CPU and completely froze. **I am able to consistently reproduce this behavior**. Any idea if it's a bug or have I done some no-no?

```
$anew -match '((.*)+([v]\d{1}\.\d{1}\..*)$)'
```

$anew is an array of about 35 lines long, which holds config dump from a server. It looks similar to this:

Directory: \aaa.net\builds\directedbuilds\bbbb\ccc\dddd\eee

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        10/15/2012   6:12 PM            v2.1.0.69
Environment                          : AB-34
Servers_in_Environment               : SERVER01;SERVER02
NgatRootFolder                       : E:\DIRNAME
PFXfilename                          : star.dom.net.pfx
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern starts with `(.*)+`, this is likely to lead to O(n<sup>3</sup>) performance, due to backtracking. You should probably use `(^(.*)([v]\d{1}\.\d{1}\..*)$)` (no extra +, and anchored) to avoid issues with very slow backtracking evaluation.

Comment: Would you be able to answer this: How do I select only the later portion of the string using regex: Build updated from v2.1.0.79 to v2.1.0.70 (I keep getting the full line using the following regex '([v]\d{1}\..{1,10})$'    Thanks